# Surjective function reasoning.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, definition

If i have a function, 
$$f : X \to Y$$
Does it make sense to say the following:

For $x \in X $ and $y \in Y, $

$f$ is not surjective if $f(x)  \neq  y$ for some $ y \in Y$.

And $f$ is not injective if $ f(x) =f(x') $,  where $x \neq x'$.

First time learning about functions in such a formal way and I don't have very detailed notes to learn off.
p.s, any text recommendations which may aid my understanding about this topic and the basis of analysis in general?

Comment: Your statement about surjectivity makes sense, but is incorrect.  The correct statement is: $f$ fails to be surjective if $Y$ contains an element $y$ that is not the image, by $f$, of any $x$ in $X$.

Comment: @user8960 if it makes sense, what makes it incorrect?

Comment: @user8960 but I completely understand your statement, $f$ is not surjective if $codom(f)  \neq Im(f) $.

Comment: What makes it incorrect? Because you haven't specified what $x$ is: did you mean *every* $x$ in $X$, or just *at least one* $x$?  (Actually, these gaps make the statement nonsensical.  So I am revising my first comment.:)

Comment: "Is not" what?  Also, not sure what the crossed out arrow means.  In general, my recommendation is to favor prose over notation.  Think of notation as a necessary evil.:)

Comment: @user8960 what about the following : $f$ is 'surjective' not if $ f: x \not\mapsto y$ for some $x \in X $.

Comment: @user8960 corrected, but okay, thanks for the advice :).

Answer (score 1):

What's really missing from your statements are quantifiers, without which it's hard to define these things. It's correct to say that $f$ is not surjective if *there exists* some $y$ for which *there does not exist* any $x$ with $f(x)=y$.

Similarly, $f$ is not injective if *there exist* some $x$ and $x'$ with $x\neq x'$ and $f(x)=f(x')$.

Comment: Would the following statement be more correct? $f$ is not surjective if $\exists\, x \in X \, \,  s. t. \, \,  f(x) \neq y$?

Comment: No. $(\exists y\in Y)(\forall x\in X)\,f(x)\ne y$. When you "say" something like "$f(x)\ne y$", you have to introduce $x$ and $y$ with quantifiers $\forall$ or $\exists$.

Comment: @Gurjinder No. $f$ is not surjective iff $\exists y \in Y \neg \exists x \in X \: f(x) = y$

Comment: @Bram28 : to avoid headaches with logic, correct and disambiguating parenthesis is mandatory :-)

Comment: @Bram28 cool understood.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS Yeah, your expression is indeed far more readable. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely grasping the concepts. You are using the contrapositive approach for your logic of injection. For instance $x\neq y\Rightarrow f(x)\neq f(y)$ so the contrapositive proof is simpler since proving equality is much more straightforward: $f(x)=f(y)\Rightarrow x=y$. So as you mention, a function is not injective if the antecedent in the contrapositive approach is true and the consequent is false.

For surjectivity I would tweak your definition to say that some $f$ is *not* surjective if for some $b$ in the codomain, there is no $x$ in the domain such that $f(x)=b$. Or more formally

For $f:A\rightarrow B$

$\exists b\in B,f(x)\neq b,\forall x\in A$

Also, for a good source... here is a nice overview of the theoretical side of functions: http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/Functions.pdf

The exercises in the chapter are also useful.

Comment: Brilliant, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To exemplify the problem in your statement "$f$ is not surjective if $(\exists x\in X) f(x)\ne y$", suppose 
$$f:\mathbb R\to\left\{0,1\right\}, x\mapsto 1 \text{ if }x=0,\, 0\text{ otherwise}$$
($f$ is the indicator function of $0$). Now if I say $y=1$, then there exists $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)\ne y$ : take $x=1$. And if I say $y=0$, there is **also** $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)\ne y$ : take $x=0$. But $f$ **is** surjective.

So you see your sentence doesn't mean anything if you don't say for which $y$ you want it to be true, one, several or all (and BTW, the quantificator on $x$ must be $\forall$, not $\exists$ ! The negation of "there exists an $x$ such that $P(x)$" is "for no $x$, $P(x)$", or "for all $x$, $\neg P(x)$).

Comment: Perfect,thank you for your time.